# Problema con las "ñ" y "Ñ"

Tags: java, xml

estoy teniendo un problema al momento de castear un nombre con Ñ en un xml, me lo cambia por "╦" y si es el caso de una ñ(minuscula) por "±". Alguien ha tenido o experimentado algo similar, y que tenga una solución! muchas gracias!

anexo parte del xml

```
<cfdi:Comprobante 
  xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  Descuento="0.00" Exportacion="01" Fecha="2022-12-02T18:36:49"Version="4.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd">
  <cfdi:Emisor Nombre="" RegimenFiscal="" Rfc=""/>
  <cfdi:Receptor  Nombre="LARA NU╦EZ" />
```

Comment: Tienes que escapar esos caracteres para que no rompan el XML. Si incluyes el código que genera/procesa el XML, pueden ayudarte

Comment: Es importante declarar correctamente como se ha codificado el documento, is es UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 o Windows-1252. Tambien ten en cuenta la codificación de la consola o donde tratas de ver el resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la respuesta, mi problema era que el **CMD de Windows** no permite caracteres especiales, encontré la forma de hacerlo, usando esto:

> @Echo OFF & CHCP 1252 1>NUL java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

espero le sirva a alguien algún día!

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Por qué nunca mencionaste que el problema era con la consola? También sería genial si explicaras para qué sirve cada comando ([editando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/572020/edit) la respuesta). Las mejores respuestas no suelen ser las que dicen "hice esto y me funciono". En este caso puedes mejorar la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar este problema, debes asegurarte de utilizar la codificación adecuada en tu archivo XML. Por ejemplo, si estás utilizando UTF-8, debes agregar la siguiente línea al inicio de tu archivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

De esta manera, se indica al procesador XML que la codificación utilizada es UTF-8, lo que permite que se guarden y leen caracteres especiales como la Ñ y la ñ correctamente.

Además, también puedes utilizar la función escapeXml() de la clase String en Java para escapar cualquier caracter especial en el XML, de esta manera:

```
String nombre = "LARA NUÑEZ";
nombre = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(nombre);
```

Esto te permitirá tener un XML correctamente codificado y sin caracteres extraños.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar y transformarlos en caracteres html:

```
&Ntilde; =Ñ

&ntilde; =ñ

Html.fromHtml(...);
```

https://ascii.cl/es/codigos-html.htm